# Expression for $order(A)-rank(A)$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-rank

I have came across a strange expression today:

```
the defect of the stiffness matrices K
```

It was used in [this paper](http://homel.vsb.cz/~kuc14/papers_accepted/DosHorKucTFETI-2005.pdf). If I understand it correctly, it's used there
to describe the number of linearly dependent rows in a symmetric matrix, but I'm not able to find any definition, so I suppose there must be some more frequently used expression for this.

So, if I have a matrix $A$ of order $n$ and $rank(A) = m$, how is properly called the value $n-m$?

Comment: Hmm... I’ve mostly heard the term “defective matrix” in the context of the number of linearly independent eigenvectors the matrix has, not its rank.

Comment: It should be [nullity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank%E2%80%93nullity_theorem).